# Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac, microphone distortion

Tags: mac, windows-11, microphone, apple-remote-desktop

I'm connecting from macOS Ventura to a Windows 11 Pro machine through Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac. The remote audio is enabled and the microphone is working but the recorded sound is considerably distorted, with metallic sound and choppy sound.

All the systems and softwares are updated (RDP for Mac version 10.8.1) and the microphone works perfectly when used locally and not through RDP. The connection quality is great (LAN), the remote audio is perfect when connected from another Windows 11 Pro to the same host.

Tested the same configuration from another client with macOS Sierra and the microphone distortion still occurs.
Everything seems to indicate that the issue is coming specifically from the app Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Is it better to switch to another remote connection protocol/software?

- Update:
  This issue seems not to happen when connecting the macOS system to a Windows 10 host. More tests will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the different "Format" of your input setting?
You can change that in the app "Audio-MIDI-Setup" [1]
Maybe you need to restart the app (which are you using? the offical one with the red icon) after that.

I had distorted audio output on my M1 Pro MBP 16". Chaning that value did fix it for now.

Tobi

[1] https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/audio-midi-setup/ams875bae1e0/mac

Comment: I tried to switch the input settings on macos to one of the windows standards (2ch, 16bit, 48 kHz) but nothing changed. There are still big chunks of voice missing during the rdp session.